# Something like exec() to return a value in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, exec

I am under the impression (perhaps wrongly) that the 'exec' function in Perl does not return a value  (I get the impression it just runs the command).  The situation is that a Perl script is running on a server and I need to invoke this script to run commands inside the Linux box, but also *return* the results. How can this be done?

Comment: [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) doesn't return at all. Are you referring to `system`? Do you want the return status of the child process, or the output?

Comment: Nitpick: `exec` can return on some failure cases, such as executable not found or not executable.

Comment: Seriously, how hard to actually take a look at `perldoc -f exec` before you post? Sure, you have every right to post this, and I'll actually upvote the correct answers, but I sure wouldn't want to have to work with someone who cannot bring himself to actually read any documentation at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by "return the results" you mean return STDOUT of the commands, what you need is backticks or `qx()`. E.g.:

```
my $result = qx(echo foo);
# or
my $result2 = `echo foo`;
```

Do note that messages to STDERR are not returned.

If you mean the exit status of the program, use system:

```
my $status = system("echo foo");
# or
my $status2 = system("/bin/echo", "foo", "bar");
```

Comment: Thanks, but what am I doing wrong here--------> ...
 my $result = qx(echo ping -c 4 www.google.com);
 return $result;
}

Comment: @JohnR The command should be exactly as you enter it in the shell. I suspect what you meant to do was `qx(ping -c 4 www.google.com)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know Perl.

Comment: @JohnR Now you know a little more. =)

Answer (score 3):

Not only does exec() not return a value, it does not return *at all*.

> `perldoc -f exec`
>
> The exec function executes a system command and never returns
>       use system instead of exec if you want it to return.

But I'm pretty sure that you do NOT want the return value of system(),
you seem to want the *output* of the command, so:

> `perldoc -f system`
>
> This is not what you want to use to capture
>       the output from a command, for that you should use merely backticks or
>       qx//, as described in perlop/"`STRING`".

Answer (score 2):

The usual perl way to run a program and save its results is [backticks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators):

```
my $foo = `ls`;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation : http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

I generally use this :

```
if(system(@args) != 0)
{
if ($? == -1) {
        print "failed to execute: $!\n";
    }
    elsif ($? & 127) {
        printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
            ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
    }
    else {
        printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Capture STDOUT:

```
my $dir = `pwd`;
my $dir = qx/pwd/;
```

---

#### Capture Return Status:

```
my $rc = system('pwd');
```

---

#### [Perldocs Capture STDERR and STDOUT](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx%2fSTRING%2f):

```
my $output = `cmd 2>&1`;
```

*See the link for other ways to capture one, output stream, but not the other*

Comment: "my system('pwd');"?? I guess you mean "my $rc = system('pwd');" :)

Answer (score 0):

using the back-tic

```
my $var = `shell command`;
```

in perl allows you to execute shell commands and it returns whatever the output was.